# How we can add .scss file for our custom module ? How it will compile to styles.css in Magento 1.9.2.1?

Tags: css, ce-1.9.2.1, scss, skin

Default RWD interface using a `skin\frontend\rwd\default\scss` folder. These group of files convert their style code into single styles.css file which located at `skin\frontend\rwd\default\css\styles.css`

How such `.scss` files get converting their style into `styles.css` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the next tutorial of Magento: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html#theme-compass

1.) You must configure a Compass Watchers to generate the css from scss

2.) And add your own Sass Partials for your custom module: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html#customze-theme-sass-partials

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a tool like  [compass](http://compass-style.org/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or something.

here is good document if you want to follow compass

http://twincreations.co.uk/setup-sass-for-magento-1-9-ce-on-windows-7/

There are several tool out there to compile scss files.

Another option is to implemnt a php based compiler like leafo/scssphp.

*i am not associate with above link at any. this is just for your knowledge*